# How to setup local environment variables for Cloud SQL (GAE) on Windows

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying an PHP app on GAE. You can define the connection variables for the Cloud SQL connection in the app.yaml file. However, I also need to define these for the MySQL server in my local dev environment.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#testing_and_deploying) suggests to do this with "export", but I am currently on Windows. PhpStorm gives me the option to define environment variables in the GAE run configuration, but those do not seem to register (at least I can't get to them using getenv).

What is a good way to specify the local connection variables for MySQL? Preferably in such a way that I don't need to make changes when uploading to Google and, if possible, without putting these details in the code.

I am running the PHP supplied with the GAE SDK (actually starting it from PhpStorm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on setting the environment variables in Windows/PhpStorm. I now added two sets of variables in app.yaml, one extra for DEV:

```
    env_variables:
      MYSQL_DEV_DSN: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=name_of_db'
      MYSQL_DEV_USERNAME: 'db_username'
      MYSQL_DEV_PASSWORD: 'db_password'
      MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;dbname=DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root_pwd'
```

And I switch between the two sets with a simple line checking what environment we are at:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Development', 0) === 0) {
  // Development
} else {
  // Google App Engine
}
```

Not quite as neat as I wanted, but works perfectly.